# Is there an ATM in Lille Europe station?

Tags: atms, eurostar, lille

Due to mis-reading the bus timetable, I failed to pick up any Euro notes, leaving me with just a handful of coins.

Were I to be arriving into Lille Europe, and then heading into the city centre, then this would be fine. The [Transpole](http://www.transpole.fr/) ticket machine take cards, so for someone wanting to take the metro or bus or tram that's fine. If you were opting to walk it (it's sub 10 minutes to the Grand Place), then there's a number of ATMs / cash machines along the way.

I, however, will be setting off on foot away from the city, and a quick check on Google Maps Streetview doesn't show any banks along the way between Lille Europe station and the bar I'm heading to.

Therefore, I figure that finding an ATM within Lille Europe station is likely to be my best bet for getting some cash out. Is there an ATM in the station? And if so, where within the station?

Comment: http://www.visa.com/atmlocator/ and http://www.mastercard.us/cardholder-services/atm-locator.html are your friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is! But it's slightly hidden, and you'll probably miss it on your first attempt... (I certainly did!)

Towards the north end of the station, not that far from the Eurostar checkin, are the toilets and a Bureau de Change. Hidden away in the wall between the two is the sole ATM in the station. As of June 2014, it's run by Societe Generale, and therefore doesn't charge any extra fees for most people.

If you look on the [SNCF map of Lille Europe Station](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/fr/frlle/plans/gare/0/), and look around the area labelled "Hall 3", you'll spy the logo for it. Basically, head for the Bureau de Change or Toilets, and look carefully between the two, and lo ye shall find the ATM of which ye searches!

If all else fails, at various points in the station are maps, which include a red "vous êtes ici" marker. Check them, and use those to narrow in on the ATM (or whatever else it was you were looking for). Lille Europe station is something like 500m long, so you can end up walking rather a lot of you don't spot it and keep going...

Answer (score 2):

According to [eurostar.com](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-information/at-our-stations/lille-europe/station-information#.U5IKLemKCUk), there are ATM Machines in Lille Europe station. In addition to that, there is a shopping area ([Euralille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euralille)) within [walking distance](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Gare+de+Lille-Europe/Euralille,+100+Centre+Commercial,+59777+Euralille,+France/@50.6377895,3.0748633,17z/data=!3m1!5s0x47c2d58ac7bf5a69:0x55f0c588f84110ab!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xd68d5576a67a5f64!2m2!1d3.075855!2d50.638811!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c2d58ac6848f7f:0xbcd72346ac4a66ba!2m2!1d3.074171!2d50.637675), it also has ATMs.